# Sending MPLS tagged packets from a Linux application

Tags: linux, tap, tun, mpls

I have written some VPN software which now needs to be able to be able to tag de-tunnelled traffic with MPLS tags.

I've looked at the source of Mausezahn (which can send MPLS packets) and it seems to construct the whole *ethernet* frame, using various helper functions, and then gives that ethernet frame to the kernel with `libnet_write`.

staging/send_eth.c:

```
     ...
     tmpls = libnet_build_mpls(tx.mpls_label,
                   tx.mpls_exp,
                   tx.mpls_bos,
                   tx.mpls_ttl,
                   NULL,
                   0,
                   l,
                   0);
     ...
     t = libnet_build_ethernet (tx.eth_dst,
                tx.eth_src,
                tx.eth_type,
                tx.eth_payload,
                tx.eth_payload_s,
                L,
                t);
     if (t == -1)
     {
          fprintf(stderr, " mz/create_eth_frame: Can't build Ethernet header: %s\n",
          libnet_geterror(l));
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }
     if (verbose) (void) print_frame_details();
     libnet_write(L);
     ...
```

My code currently uses an IP-level tunnel interface (e.g. tun0) to deliver packets into the kernel.

If I wish to use MPLS will I need to start using a tap interface instead?

Or is there another way, such as ioctls on tun0's fd?

Or do I need to use `libnet_write`?